# chainload multiple grub2 bootloaders

Tags: grub2, boot-loader

This is the context:
I have a laptop with one hd which contains 4 partitions:

- 2 for windows: (hd0,1), (hd0,2) -> For windows 7
- 2 for linux: (hd0,3), (hd0,4) -> For linux (logical partitions).

The current "real" bootloader (in the MBR I mean) is the windows one.
Behind, I use [grub2win](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/) for specific purposes, and I would use it to chainload grub2 which is on (hd0,3).

Here is the entry I added in grub.cfg to do this:

```
menuentry 'Chainloader 3' {
   insmod chain
   set root=(hd0,3)
   chainloader +1
}
```

Unhappily, when I try to use it, I just have "nothing", a black screen without any error, and I really don't know what to do more.

Here is the result of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa2c2c4f8

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   209717247   104857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       209717248   420339711   105311232    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       420341758   625141759   102400001    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       420341760   615651327    97654784   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       615653376   625141759     4744192   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: please don't edit grub.cfg file.

Comment: User interface of grub2win is limited. I don't see another way to load ISOs or chainload another grub than by editing grub.cfg. But if  there is another solution, tell me, I will use it next time.

Comment: Ok, I finally found by chance.

If you have the same problem, it can maybe help... :
* Go to the grub command prompt (just type C when grub2win has started)
* Then, use "ls" in order to view the list of accessible drives/partitions
* In my case, I hadn't to use:
    set root=(hd0,3)
But instead:
    set root=(hd0,msdos3)

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip:

Logical partitions allways start at number five. Check you have not misstyped the numbers 3 and 4, maybe they must be 5 and 6... or you have four primary partitions!

Are you really sure you have the other grub on partition number 3 (that is the extended definition, not a partition itself), maybe you are refering to partition number FIVE.

From fdisk i see you have two primary partitions (1 & 2), an extended partition (3) and two logical partitions (5 & 6).

I never ever see installed a Grub onto the Extended itself, but i saw grub installed on partition boot sector (on your case could be 5 or 6, not 3).

Another tip:

When on Grub2 menu, jou can press the 'c' key to go to command line, then type the command `ls`, that will show you the names of the partitions, disks, etc it can see; then take note of them to see the pattern (hd0,5) or (hd0,msdos5) or (hd0,gpt5), etc. To return to menu just press the key 'Esc'.

I am quite sure you misstyped the numbers, since you say "2 for linux: (hd0,3), (hd0,4) -> For linux (logical partitions)." but fdisk shows there are only two primary partitions (1 & 2); also your partition number 3 is the Extended definition, not a plce where you can put a filesystem.

So maybe you would say (4 & 5 instead of 3 & 4):

2 for linux: (hd0,4), (hd0,5) -> For linux (logical partitions).

Is it a typpo mistake? Or are you really trying to reference first sector of the Extended partition, where it resides the logicals partitions definition, hope first, else if you write there you will damage logicals partitions definiton nad so causing them to not be accesible. By luck Grub installer does not allow to install onto that place.

Hope you can fix your question.

And yes, Grub can reside inside a Ext4 that is inside a striped LVM across multiple disks, and also you can add as much LUKS as you want on any part of the chain; Grub is wonderfull for such things.

I mean: grub.cfg file and the rest of files can e inside this complex sample scheme:

- HDD0: No primary partitions at all, only one Extended with one logical having LUKS (Key A), inside it a LVM2 definition
- HDD1: No primary partitions at all, only one Extended with one logical having LUKS (Key B), inside it a LVM2 definition
- HDD2: No primary partitions at all, only one Extended with one logical having LUKS (Key C), inside it a LVM2 definition
- Such LVM2 combined (striped) into a BIG virtual disk, having as many logical volumes as you want (also you can use LUKS over them), one for Grub and its files

etc.

Remember: If you are not sure what literal Grub uses, go to a command line (pressing 'c' key) and use command `ls` without paramenter, then take note of the sintax and what it sees, to return to menu just use the 'Esc' key.

This is also helpfull for when you use crypto devices (LUKS) and also LVM.